# Конфликт библиотек Java в DrJava

Tags: java, library

Существует проблема: установил Java библиотеку (среда программирования DrJava) созданную моим учителем, а она стала конфликтовать с java.util.* из за коллектора Queue. Проблема состоит в том что в одном из заданий мне нужно использовать Scanner и Queue вместе. Можно ли отдать приоритет какой-то библиотеке? И как это исправить?

### Ошибки

1. Error: reference to Queue is ambiguous
   both class unit4.collectionsLib.Queue in unit4.collectionsLib and interface java.util.Queue in java.util match
2. Error: reference to Queue is ambiguous
   both class unit4.collectionsLib.Queue in unit4.collectionsLib and interface java.util.Queue in java.util match

### Библиотеки

```
import java.util.*;
import unit4.collectionsLib.*;
```

Comment: Пишите в коде полное название классов с пакетами, например так: `java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: @Алексей Швачко а как зовут вашего учителя, если не секрет?

Comment: Не используйте импорт со звездочкой.

Comment: @LexHobbit Перехожу в подгруппу Евгения Канеля. А что?)

Comment: @Nofate А что изменится? и зачем так делать?

Comment: Когда вы импортируете через звездочку, в область видимость попадают все классы пакета. И очевидно ваш `unit4.collectionsLib.Queue` конфликтует с `java.util.Queue`, о чем написано в сообщении об ошибке. И вам нужно выбрать к кому из них вы будете обращаться по короткому имени `Queue`.

Comment: @Nofate Благодарю, я попробую